# Error Cannot find symbol & seems my driver class is not linking with other classes

Tags: java, arraylist

> You will need to check that the four parameters entered by the user
>   are blank, so you will do the same as you did before but four times.
>
> To Identify if the User Presses `<enter>`
>
> You have written a JAVA program that creates a CD object with four
>   instance variables, along with a CDException.java class that helps you
>   validate this input. So far you have been using these classes with my
>   driver classes. Now it is time for you to create a real driver class
>   that will implement an ArrayList of CD objects. Here is a list of
>   requirements for your LAST program
>
> - Read the artist name from the user
> - Read the album name from the user
> - Read the number of items in stock
> - Read the price of the album
>
> Your program should continue to read the CD information from the user until all the entries from the user for all the fields are blank. Your program will then print the list all the "valid" CDs entered by the
>   user.

I keep getting errors like this

```
CDStore.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
Disk d;
^
symbol: class Disk
location: class CDStore

CDStore.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
catch(CDException cde){
^
symbol: class CDException
location: class CDStore

CDStore.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
for(int i = 0; i < CDShelf.length( ); i++){
^
symbol: method length()
location: variable CDShelf of type ArrayList

CDStore.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
d = (Disk)(CD.get(i));
^
symbol: class Disk
location: class CDStore

CDStore.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
d = (Disk)(CD.get(i));
^
symbol: method get(int)
location: class CD
5 errors
```

**And it looks like that my driver class here is not linking with my exception class. Any help would be much appreciated on how to get rid of these errors!**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class CDStore{
        public static void main (String[ ] arg)throws Exception{

     String sArtist = "";
     String sAlbum = "";
     int inStock = 0;
     double dPrice = 0;
     String C = "";
     Disk d;
     int count = 0;
     boolean exit = false;


     Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
     ArrayList CDShelf = new ArrayList( );

      do{
        try{
            System.out.print("What is the Artist name: ");
            sArtist = reader.nextLine( );
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);

            if(sArtist.length( ) < 1){
               exit = true;
         }

            System.out.print("What is the album name: ");
            sAlbum = reader.nextLine( );
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);

            if(sAlbum.length( ) < 1){
               exit = true;
         }
            System.out.print("What is the price: ");
            dPrice = reader.nextDouble( );
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);

            if(dPrice < 1){
               exit = true;
         }
            System.out.print("How many are in stock: ");
            inStock = reader.nextInt( );
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            d = new CD(sArtist, sAlbum, dPrice, inStock);

            if(inStock < 1){
               exit = true;
         }

            CD.add(d);
            count++;
            System.out.println(C.toString( ));
            System.out.println("=============================");
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ime){
            System.out.println("You didnt do it");
        }
        catch(CDException cde){
            System.out.println(cde.getMessage( ));
        }
    }while(count < 3);

    System.out.println("This is what you entered");
    for(int i = 0; i < CDShelf.length( ); i++){
        d = (Disk)(CD.get(i));
        System.out.println(d.toString( ));
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really use and IDE. Have you tried [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/downloads/)?

Comment: No. Per my instructor, we have to use jGrasp. Why, is that one easier?

Comment: The class `Disk` cannot be found.

Comment: Na, @acdcjunior just likes to torture people with Eclipse.

Comment: how would I go about initializing it or whatever? I know this has got to be a simple fix, I just cant figure it out, I've been working on it for awhile now. It's frustrating me.